# Why write Vue props with redundant `type` and `validator`?

Tags: vue.js

In the source for the [vue-typeahead-bootstrap](https://github.com/mattzollinhofer/vue-typeahead-bootstrap/blob/master/src/components/VueBootstrapTypeahead.vue#L80-L89) component, there are props with a `type` and `validator` defined:

```
data: {
  type: Array,
  required: true,
  validator: d => d instanceof Array
},
serializer: {
  type: Function,
  default: (d) => d,
  validator: d => d instanceof Function
},
```

These `type` and `validator` options seem redundant, since the `validator` is enforcing the same data type as each respective prop's `type`. As far as I'm aware, Vue already checks prop types internally, which would make this unnecessary. What is the purpose of this approach? Could the custom `validator`s simply be removed?

Comment: I think this question is too specific for the developers of that library. It does seem redundant since the type config checks that using instanceof method https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Type-Checks `In addition, type can also be a custom constructor function and the assertion will be made with an instanceof check`

Comment: I agree the validators in this case are indeed redundant and have no benefit or hidden purpose. Actually, Vue's own [type-assertion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/ec78fc8b6d03e59da669be1adf4b4b5abf670a34/dist/vue.runtime.js#L1724-L1745) is more thorough. You could submit a Github PR to remove the redundant lines from `vue-typeahead-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Tiessen points out in his [article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/unlock-full-potential-prop-types/), just use:

```
// Use return function with boolean return value
(prop) => return propIsValid;
```

Comment: This generally describes how to define a validator, but that doesn't answer the question, which is specifically about the apparently redundant validator from `vue-typeahead-bootstrap`'s source.

Comment: Hmm, yes I suppose you are right, that is more well-defined topic...